# WCF "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception"

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

We have an existing system that uses WCF and was working fine until yesterday, when suddenly it stopped working on both my machine and another developer machine.

I've setup system diagnostics in the client config to write a trace file and we see the following exception:

```
Throwing an exception 

**Basic Information**

Activity Name           Receive bytes on connection 'net.tcp://localhost:8004/'.
Time                    2016-01-06 13:38:45.3958
Level                   Error
Source                  System.ServiceModel
Process                 NServiceBus.Host
Thread                  219
Computer                RL-ZORO-LPT
Trace Identifier/Code   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx


**Exception**

System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
         System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Exception Type: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Message: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.

Stack Trace:  System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptorAsyncResult.CompleteAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult result)
              System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptorAsyncResult.OnAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult result)
              System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
              System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
              System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
              System.Net.Security.SslState.FinishHandshake(Exception e, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              System.Net.Security.SslState.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32 result)
              System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes)
              System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
              System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
              System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(Object state)
              System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
              System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
              System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
              System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
              System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Our **server** configuration looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ServerImpl.RACServiceImpl.RACService" behaviorConfiguration="BILLService.ServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.Tcp://localhost:8004" />
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8006" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="BILLService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConf" contract="ServerImpl.Rsp.ServiceInterfaces.IRACService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="RACServer" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.Tcp://localhost:8001/RMACService" behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConf" contract="ServerImpl.Rsp.ServiceInterfaces.IRACService" name="IRACService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="RACServer" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BILLService.ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="RACServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <clientCertificate>
              <certificate findValue="RACClient" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="40" maxConcurrentInstances="40" maxConcurrentSessions="40" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="RACClient" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="RACServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBindingConf" closeTimeout="00:11:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="100" openTimeout="00:20:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:15:00" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is our **client** configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBinding_RACService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:40:00" receiveTimeout="00:32:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IThirdPartyRACService" closeTimeout="00:59:00" openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"></message>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.Tcp://localhost:8004/AMACService" behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding_RACService" contract="ServerImpl.Rsp.ServiceInterfaces.IRACService" name="IRACService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="RACServer" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.Tcp://localhost:8004/AMACService" behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding_RACService" contract="ServerImpl.Rsp.ServiceInterfaces.IRACService" name="IRACService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="RACServer" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="https://localhost/ThirdPartyWebService/ThirdPartyRACService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IThirdPartyRACService" contract="IThirdPartyRACService" name="WSHttpBinding_IThirdPartyRACService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="RACClient" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="RACServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If we set the security mode to "None" on **both** the client and the server then it works.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Why is the trace not writing the inner exception?  Who wrote the trace?

Comment: @Will don't know, there was no inner exception.

Comment: Enable service tracing in the **server** config instead.

Comment: Yeah, somehow I don't believe there wasn't an inner exception.

Comment: The security mode between your client and your service don't match - I would expect that to be the reason you're seeing the error.

Comment: @Tim why out of nowhere? both the server and the client run on the same machine. Same on other developer machine.

Comment: @Tim don't know. We did a git clean and recompiled and since then we have this problem. In windows event log we found the following error: "A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 40. The Windows SChannel error state is 1205."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that what was causing the problem is a windows update that happened that same day (strange coincidence). The update is `kb3102467` (aka .NET Framework 4.6.1) - which will eventually find itself on the machine.

As it turns out, the SSL certificate we are using uses RSA/SHA512, which from what I've read caused high CPU usage and was therefor disabled (there was a hotfix for this issue and registry information that I saw was added, but after kb3102467 it still happened).

As a workaround (until we issue new SSL certificates) I have disabled TLS 1.2 in the following manner:

1. Start regedit and browse to the following location: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SChannel\Protocols
2. Create the following Key under Protocol: TLS 1.2
3. Create the following two Keys under TLS 1.2: Client and Server
4. Create the following DWORDs under both the Client and Server Key: DisabledByDefault and Enabled
5. Under both Client and Server set the following: DisabledByDefault=1 and Enabled =0
6. Reboot the server.

That solved the problem without the need to uninstall `kb3102467`

Comment: While this may have worked for the OP in 2016, I encourage others to be cautious. I tried this solution and it impaired my entire machine's ability to connect to SSL sites. In other words, buyer beware, and be prepared to roll this back. I needed to roll this back.

Answer (score 2):

I got an error while testing this on localhost on windows 10 and thought to share with you all.

In App.Config on the client side i removed/commented below line :

```
  <!--<identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="AD\7329688" />
            </identity>-->
```

Now its working

Comment: Yes, this is a very good answer and helped me too. Thanks a lot.